# Solving absolute inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have the following inequality:
$$|4 - k^2| > |10 + 13k|$$
So how to solve this ?

Comment: Is $k$ real or complex?

Comment: @DanielFischer $k$ is real

Comment: Then a case distinction would be an easy way to find all possible $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer , I know that my question is so simple, but i stick with this problem , could you help me ?

Comment: Consider the cases $k \geqslant 2$, $-\frac{10}{13} \leqslant k < 2$, $-2\leqslant k < -\frac{10}{13}$ and $k < -2$ separately.

Comment: @DanielFischer If $k$ was complex the problem was still not hard but more dirty :)

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Start by sketching the graphs $y=|4-x^2|$ and $y=|10+13x|$. To do this, sketch $y=4-x^2$ and $y=10+13x$ and reflect anything below the $x$-axis back up above the $x$-axis.

Next, solve the two equations $4-x^2 = \pm(10+13x)$.

Use your sketch to help you find the regions where $|4-x^2| >  |10+13x|$.